# centering responsive matrix on the page

Tags: css

My objective is to vertically center the following responsive matrix, so that both on the left and right will be the same distance to the edge of the screen (parent has a width of 100%). Could you please help? Thank you. My code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>image matrix</title>
    <style>
        html, body{margin: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;}
        .container {
            width: 100%;
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(190px, 1fr));
        }

        .cell {
            border: 0px solid darkred;
            height: 50px;
            width: 150px;
            margin: 20px;
            background-color: #058;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<!-- this program illustrates responsive design without the use of media queries -->

    <div class="container">
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: all you need is justify-content: center; to container

Comment: You are right! Thank you Temani.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **Flexbox**, you can achieve the same with the following code.
Your cells will always stay in the center and no need to use any media query as required.

```css
 
        html, body{
          margin: 0; width: 100%;  
          height: 100%;
        }

        .container {
            width: 100vw;
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap:wrap;
            justify-content:center;
        }

        .cell {
            border: 0px solid darkred;
            height: 50px;
            margin: 20px;
            background-color: #058;
            flex-basis:150px;
        }
```

```html
<!-- this program illustrates responsive design without the use of media queries -->

    <div class="container">
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
    </div>
```

**CODEPEN LINK** : https://codepen.io/emmeiWhite/pen/vYeZayL

Comment: Hello Imran. Your solution is great. Thank you. Is there a way of aligning to the left the cells of the last row, in case the number of elements there is lower compared to the other rows?

Comment: Yes, There is a way. We need to target the last elements smartly using pseudo classes and and properties on individual elements.

Give this a try https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ and explore more.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `margin: 0px auto ;`to your container.

```css
      html, body{margin: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;}
        .container {
            width: 60%;
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(190px, 1fr));
            margin: 0px auto ;
        }

        .cell {
            border: 0px solid darkred;
            height: 50px;
            width: 150px;
            margin: 20px;
            background-color: #058;
        }
```

```html
<!-- this program illustrates responsive design without the use of media queries -->

    <div class="container">
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
    </div>
```